# Sticky content scrolling up into fixed menu header Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

So I've set up some sticky rail content using an example for the [SUIR docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky/#types-adjacent-context). However, when scrolling the main content, the rail content scrolls into my fixed header.

Do I need to set more rules on the style prop for `<Rail>`?

[Codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk0970zypl)

To view the issue, navigate to `Docs` from the menu bar.
The `<Rail>` component is at the bottom of `Overview.js` file

```
export default class Overview extends Component {
  contextRef = createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FixedMenuLayout />
        <Grid centered columns={3} style={{ marginTop: "7em" }}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Ref innerRef={this.contextRef}>
              <Segment>
                <Docs />

                <Rail position="left">
                  <Sticky context={this.contextRef}>
                    <Header as="h3">Getting Started</Header>
                    <List style={{ padding: "5px" }}>
                      <List.Item>Overview</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Examples</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Tutorial</List.Item>
                    </List>
                    <Header as="h3">How To</Header>
                    <List style={{ padding: "5px" }}>
                      <List.Item>Building</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Standalone</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Deployment</List.Item>
                    </List>
                    <Header as="h3">Development</Header>
                    <List style={{ padding: "5px" }}>
                      <List.Item>Road Map</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Upcoming Features</List.Item>
                    </List>
                  </Sticky>
                </Rail>

                <Rail position="right">
                  <Sticky context={this.contextRef}>
                    <Header as="h3">Overview</Header>
                    <List style={{ padding: "5px" }}>
                      <List.Item>Overview</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Examples</List.Item>
                      <List.Item>Tutorial</List.Item>
                    </List>
                  </Sticky>
                </Rail>
              </Segment>
            </Ref>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a rather easy fix just didn't see the correct prop that handles this exact issue.

The [`offset`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky/#usage-offset) prop for `<Sticky>` needs to be set to an appropriate value.

In my case,

```
<Sticky offset={90} context={this.contextRef}>
```